# Best IDE to edit and save code directly to server

Tags: javascript, css, ide, remote-access, aptana

Ok I have been using using Aptana Studio 3 for my IDE. It was great because I was able to view files directly off the server and edit and save them directly to the server. This meant I didn't have to download any files locally to my computer.

I was then dumped a horrific CMS job that runs on a Windows Server which Aptana does not connect to via ftp ([see bug here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2324-ftp-doesnt-work-with-windows-servers)). I need an alternative IDE very quickly to make progress on this project!

**Can anyone help? Either I need a fix for this Aptana Bug or I neeed an alternative IDE that will fulfil the same criteria...**

Comment: try NetBeans it will update the files as you save them on local if it supports tha language you are using http://netbeans.org/

Comment: @Devjosh can't seem to wok out how to set up an ftp connection and view the files on my server.

Comment: @pagweil see if this can help its using php but the wizard will be same if you are using some other language too

Comment: @Devjosh I don't seem to see a link?

Comment: In netbeans, go to File->Project Properties -> Run Configuration.

Comment: oops i forgot it try now http://www.netbeans.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like in your case an online IDE could work - I guess they will have all the random connection types sorted out. I would recommend [ShiftEdit](http://shiftedit.net/home), but you can take a look at the answers in [Is there an online PHP IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897/online-php-ide), too.

Answer (score 3):

I've used this only for some server side JavaScript node.js coding and it worked fine for me. Take a look at [cloud9](http://cloud9ide.com/). (You will need to have node.js running on the server.)

Edit: The website is a little bit misleading. There is a way to run this on you own server.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is very subjective… so I'll answer subjectively. [EditPad Pro](http://editpadpro.com/) (lite version free, pro version can be purchased) and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (free) have FTP support (Notepad++ via a [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=FTP_Synchronize)). Neither of these are *full* IDEs but in my experience are great editors; it really depends on what sort of code you need to edit and if you actually *need* a full IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, you could use [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) from Panic. It is a great IDE with text editor, file transfer, svn, css, terminal and many more. It provides also a remote connection with a server via FTP, SFTP, FTP with SSL or WebDAV.